# Having a problem getting a specific JavaScript event to work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

So I built a small website for showing off pictures and information about a friend's hobby. The main 'Picture' page is a bunch of thumbnails with one center full-sized image, and I designed it so that clicking a thumbnail will change the bigger picture and all the descriptions for it to match that thumbnail. This is an example image, the others are exactly like it except different names (star2, star3, that sorta thing) so the onclick event is what causes the Javascript. This works in Chrome, Opera, and IE, but it doesn't do anything in Firefox. And I know Javascript is enabled because I have other small things using Javascript (like a few buttons in the top of the page to change the size of the center image) and they work. So what's Firefox doing to make this not run?

```
<img class="thumbnail" onclick="descriptionSwap('star1'); titleSwap('star'); imageSwap('images/star1.jpg');" id="star1" title="Click me!" src="images/small_star1.jpg"/>
```

It didn't occur to me to think the problem would be the code itself since I know it works in the other browsers, I thought it would be the onclick() event in the img tags, but here's the functions I use:

```
//Changes the center image
function imageSwap(newSource) {
document.getElementById('centerimage').src = newSource;
}
//Changes the title of the picture
function titleSwap(newTitle) {
if (newTitle=='star') {
    pictureTitle.innerHTML= 'Stars';
}
}
//Changes the description
function descriptionSwap(newDescription) {
if (newDescription=='star1') {
        pictureDescription.innerHTML='
        //Big long description, cut it out to save room here.
        ';
}
}
```

I have some `<p>` tags set up with the id's "pictureTitle" and "pictureDescription" which is what the innerHTML points to in the functions.

Oh nevermind I fixed it, thanks Frédéric Hamidi for telling me about the error console. Firefox told me the `pictureDescription.innerHTML` line was wrong, and it seems so obvious now I don't even know why I wrote it that way in the first place. When I fixed it to `document.getElementById('pictureDescription').innerHTML` it fixed the issue, and I had to do the same with the pictureTitle function too. Thanks guys!

Comment: What does the actual code look like?  What sort of investigating have you done via FireBug? Are there any errors reported?

Comment: Hit `Ctrl+Shift+J` to invoke the error console and give it a look. Chances are one of your `*Swap()` functions throws an exception in Firefox.

Comment: What exactly `titleSwap('star')` does? seeing the id of the img should'nt it be `titleSwap('star1')` ? Just guessing

Comment: I didn't occur to me to think the problem would be the code itself since I know it works in the other browsers, I thought it would be the onclick() event in the img tags, but here's the functions I use:

Answer (score 0):

The function changed the `<p id="pictureDescription">` tags like this:

```
pictureDescription.innerHTML="description";
```

and it should have done it like this:

```
document.getElementById('pictureDescription').innerHTML="description";
```

The other browsers put up with that tomfoolery and made up for my mistake in the background, but Firefox had the balls to tell me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your problem is solved. Have you considered JQuery?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body {background-color: #2E2E2E}
            img {margin:auto}
            em {margin:auto;width:1280px;color:#B2B2B2}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('.thumbnail').live('click',function(){
                    $(this).attr('src', 'http://automodifiedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Black-Lamborghini-Ankonian-Concept-rear-view-2.jpeg');
                    $(this).attr('title', 'New Title');
                    $(this).attr('alt', 'New alternate description');
                    $('em.thumbnail').text('Lamborghini Ankonian Concept Rear View');
                });
                $('.thumbnail').css({'display':'block'});
            });
        </script>
        <title>Lamborghine Ankonian Concept!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="thumbnail" id="star1" alt="alt description" title="Click me!" src="http://automodifiedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Black-Lamborghini-Ankonian-Concept-rear-view-3.jpg"/>
        <em class="thumbnail">Lamborghini Ankonian Concept!</em>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Honestly, I've never used JQuery. I've heard a lot about it, but I haven't yet put the time into finding out how I can use it or what it can do. I'm just learning web development on my own in my free time so I'm still learning, and I'm trying to keep an attitude like "If it's possible to do something, I want to figure out how to do it on my own."  But thanks for the suggestion!